# How to get a list of numbers as input and calculate the sum?

Tags: python, sum

```
mylist = int(raw_input('Enter your list: '))    
total = 0    
for number in mylist:    
    total += number    
print "The sum of the numbers is:", total
```

Comment: An int is not a list. An int is also not iterable.

Answer (score 7):

Correct way of doing the same is:

```
separator = " " #Define the separator by which you are separating the input integers.
# 1,2,3,4    => separator = ","
# 1, 2, 3, 4 => separator = ", "
# 1 2 3 4    => separator = " "

mylist = map(int, raw_input("Enter your list : ").split(separator)) 

print "The sum of numbers is: "+str(sum(mylist))
```

To find the sum you need to convert the space separated characters into `int` **individually** as done above using [map](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#functional-programming-tools) function.

Comment: This might be a good time to give a very brief overview of what map is/does (and a link to its documentation.)

Comment: The OP is using `int` already, so the string concatenation part is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for fixing that.  +1 (mostly for introducing a user to `map`)

Comment: Thanks for your concern. :) appreciated

Comment: Thank you. In the print statement, why are you using the +str?

Comment: I doubt this is what @Eliza means, but why *are* you using `+` as opposed to `str.format`?

Comment: oh, Actually in python if I go like `print "The sum is :"+2` , it won't work and would raise an error, strings can only be concatenated to strings so the following 2 statements would work: `print "The sum is :"+"2"` or `print "The sum is :"+str(2)`, in the answer above the `2` is replaced by `sum` variable

Answer (score 3):

You are not creating a list. You are creating a string with your user input and attempting to convert that string to an int.

You can do something like this:

```
mylist = raw_input('Enter your list: ')
mylist = [int(x) for x in mylist.split(',')]
total = 0    
for number in mylist:    
    total += number    
print "The sum of the numbers is:", total
```

Output:

```
Enter your list:  1,2,3,4,5
The sum of the numbers is: 15
```

---

#### What did I do?

I changed your first line into:

```
mylist = raw_input('Enter your list: ')
mylist = [int(x) for x in mylist.split(',')]
```

This accepts the user's input as a comma separated string. It then converts every element in that string into an int. It does this by using [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on the string at each comma.

This method will fail if the user inputs a non-integer or they don't comma separate the input.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are attempting to convert a string of numbers that most likely looks like this(you never specified input format):

```
"1 23 4 45 4"
```

OR this

```
"1, 45, 65, 77"
```

to an `int`. This naturally won't work as only one number at a time could be converted like this. For instance `int('45')` will work, but `int('12 34, 56')` will not.

I think what you need to do is something like this:

```
mylist = raw_input("Enter a list of numbers, SEPERATED by WHITE SPACE(3 5 66 etc.): ")
# now you can use the split method of strings to get a list
mylist = mylist.split() # splits on white space by default
# to split on commas -> mylist.split(",")

# mylist will now look something like. A list of strings.
['1', '44', '56', '2'] # depending on input of course

# so now you can do
total = sum(int(i) for i in mylist)
# converting each string to an int individually while summing as you go
```

This isn't the most compact answer, but I think it breaks it down for you to better understand. Compactness can come later.

Comment: why is it saying invalid literal for int with base 10: [1, 2, 3, 4] ?

Comment: If you followed the above example exactly, this should not happen. However, it seems you are passing an entire list to int() rather than individual strings

Comment: In fact it seems more like you passed an entire list AS a string to int. For instance int('[1,2,3,4]')... can you provide the exact full traceback?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to store numbers in list, create list. also add a loop for user enters values. you can assign an input to break the loop or add a counter.

```
myList = []
counter = 0 
while counter<10: #change this to true for infinite (unlimited) loop. also remove counter variables
    num = raw_input("Enter numbers or (q)uit")
    if num == 'q': 
        break
    else:
        myList.append(int(num))
    counter +=1

print sum(myList)
```

or without list

```
>>> while True:
...     num = raw_input("number or (q)uit")
...     if num == 'q': break
...     else:
...             total +=int(num)
...
```

result

```
number or (q)uit4
number or (q)uit5
number or (q)uit6
number or (q)uit7
number or (q)uit8
number or (q)uit9
number or (q)uit9
number or (q)uitq
>>> total
48
```